# Time limit exceeded exception while updating Approval Process entry criteria

Tags: approval-process, exception

I am getting `Time limit exceeded` exception while updating Approval Process entry criteria.

Is there any other way to change the entry criteria or workaround of this exception.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This most likely happened due to your [organization being locked](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004045&language=en_US) due to a deployment.  Simply try again is your best bet.